# Java - Boolean only returns false; am I passing incorrect values?

Tags: java, methods, boolean, return

I have a 10x10 array of dots.  I ask the user for a starting point on the 'grid' and then generate a randomized walk through the grid, to the north, south, east, and west.

I have used a switch statement, dependent upon a random number, to iterate counterclockwise, checking for a '.' in each direction. If I find a dot, I move to that position on the grid, and increment an alphabetic character. The program executes until the user reaches 'Z', or until the user gets stuck - which ever happens first.

The random number is generated from 0-3. If 0, the program checks north, then east, then south, then west; if 1, it checks east, then south, and so on.

For example, if the user starts at 1,1 on the grid, he/she should be able to move in any direction, as there is nothing else on the grid. They are completely surrounded by dots.

My issue is that when I pass the next possible position from my switch statement into the boolean method, it ALWAYS returns false.

This is the boolean method:

```
public static boolean canMove(int r, int c)
{
boolean canMoveSwitch = false;
    if ((r>=0 && r <=9) && (c>=0 && c <=9))
    {
        if(walkingGrid[r][c] == '.')
        {
            canMoveSwitch = true;
        }
    }
    return canMoveSwitch;
}
```

And this is [part of] the switch:

```
public static void makeAMove()
{
    while(stopCode != 1)
    {
        getRandom();
        switch(randomDirection)
        {
            case 0: if(canMove(row-1, col) == true)//North
                    {
                        alphabetIndex = (char)alphabetIndex + 1;
                        walkingGrid[row-1][col] = (char)alphabetIndex;
                    }
                    else if(canMove(row, col+1) == true)//East
                    {
                        alphabetIndex = (char)alphabetIndex + 1;
                        walkingGrid[row][col+1] = (char)alphabetIndex;
                    }
                    else if(canMove(row+1,col) == true)//South
                    {
                        alphabetIndex = (char)alphabetIndex + 1;
                        walkingGrid[row+1][col] = (char)alphabetIndex;
                    }
                    else if(canMove(row,col-1) == true)//West
                    {
                        alphabetIndex = (char)alphabetIndex + 1;
                        walkingGrid[row][col-1] = (char)alphabetIndex;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        stopCode = 1;
                    }
                     break;
```

RandomDirection is working fine.

I have printed it from main just to make sure. Row and col are the coordinates entered by the user. At that time, they should be able to move in at least one direction, but the boolean never returns true. 
I have printed "canMoveSwitch" from the main program, so I know it is returning a true/false value.

Am I not passing the values correctly? This is for homework, so I am not really looking for an outright answer; just a shove in the right direction.
Your insight would be kindly appreciated. 
***EDIT***

I figured it out! When I printed the grid to show the user's position, I incremented row and col to their maximum value. All I had to do was get back the user's values before my switch, and it worked fine! Thanks to all who looked over this!

Comment: What is the definition of `walkingGrid`?

Comment: Have you initialized all the elements of walkingGrid to '.'?

Comment: I did initialize the array to all '.' --- public static void fillArray()
 {
  for (row=0; row<10; row++)
  {
   for (col=0; col<10; col++)
   {
    walkingGrid[row][col] = '.';
   }
  }
 }

Comment: Sorry, also: walking grid is created with----private static char walkingGrid[][] = new char[10][10]; I appreciate your time.

Comment: It's bad practice to mutate state instead of returning a value. e.g instead of `getRandom();  switch(randomDirection)` do `int randomDirection = getRandom(); switch(randomDirection)`